# How to catch/handle exceptions in WCF that occur due to type casting or passing invalid values to the variables while calling through postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, exception

I'm beginner to WCF. While building RestFul Apis, im facing the some crash issue.

On my hunt to Handling exception through WCF, i have gotten help from various sources like the following:

[WCF Exception Handling Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379917/wcf-exception-handling-strategies)
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pedram/2008/01/25/wcf-error-handling-and-some-best-practices/
https://riptutorial.com/csharp/example/5460/implementing-ierrorhandler-for-wcf-services

By implementing Global Error handler,internal exceptions of the application are being handled smoothly (by handle them in try catch clock). But Im not sure how to handle casting exceptions. I.e the exceptions that are causing crash to the application if variable gets invalid value.

**EDIT:**

I have a following DataContract class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Web;

namespace StilaarAPI.DataContracts
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Products
    {

        [DataMember]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "product Name is required")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Address Feild length should be between 5 and 50")]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "ProductID is requied")]
        [DataMember]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }



    }
    }
```

---

And following (Ajax- enabled WCF service is using the above DataContract class as input argument)

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    public string GetProduct(Products pro)
    {
        try
        {

            string test = "Every thing works fine :D";
            return test;

            //ResultDo<List<ProblemTypesDo>> result = new ResultDo<List<ProblemTypesDo>>();
            //var problemTypes = _riderOrderDeliveryBL.GetProblemType();


        }
        catch (NotFoundException ex)
        {
            NotFoundFault fault = new NotFoundFault();
            fault.Error = "Product Not Found";
            fault.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;

            throw new WebFaultException<NotFoundFault>(
                                       fault, HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }



    }
```

Calling the above service from postman just give smooth simple result:

[image]

Which is good, Now if i run different input scenarios on input variable:
Starting with setting null value to the product name, it gives me following result
[image]

Not bad, since my validation worked and exception being handled so I got the above result.
Now coming towards next scenario, if i set ID to null, following output is being occured:
[image]

Now, my question is what can I do to prevent application from crashing like that:

Following are my IError Handler classess:

```
public class GlobalErrorBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    private readonly Type errorHandlerType;

    /// <summary>
    /// Dependency injection to dynamically inject error handler if we have multiple global error handlers
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="errorHandlerType"></param>
    public GlobalErrorBehaviorAttribute(Type errorHandlerType)
    {
        this.errorHandlerType = errorHandlerType;
    }



    #region IServiceBehavior Members

    void IServiceBehavior.Validate(ServiceDescription description,
        ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    void IServiceBehavior.AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription description,
        ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase,
        Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection parameters)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registering the instance of global error handler in dispatch behavior of the service
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="description"></param>
    /// <param name="serviceHostBase"></param>
    void IServiceBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription description,
        ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        IErrorHandler errorHandler;

        try
        {
            errorHandler = (IErrorHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(errorHandlerType);
        }
        catch (MissingMethodException e)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The errorHandlerType specified in the ErrorBehaviorAttribute constructor must have a public empty constructor.", e);
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException e)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The errorHandlerType specified in the ErrorBehaviorAttribute constructor must implement System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IErrorHandler.", e);
        }

        foreach (ChannelDispatcherBase channelDispatcherBase in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher = channelDispatcherBase as ChannelDispatcher;
            channelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(errorHandler);
        }
    }

    #endregion IServiceBehavior Members



}




 public class GlobalErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {

        return true;
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error,System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion version,ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message fault)
    {

            //if (error is FaultException)
            //    return;

            var jsonError = new CustomFault
            {

                Error = "Something went wrong",
                Details = error.GetType().FullName

            };
            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, "", jsonError,
                                          new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(CustomFault)));

            // Tell WCF to use JSON encoding rather than default XML
            var wbf = new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json);
            fault.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, wbf);

            // Modify response
            var rmp = new HttpResponseMessageProperty
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                StatusDescription = "Bad Request",
            };
            rmp.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
            fault.Properties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, rmp);


    }
}



public class ExtendedWebHttpBehavior : WebHttpBehavior
{
    protected override void AddServerErrorHandlers(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        // clear default erro handlers.
        endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Clear();

        // add our own error handler.
        endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(new GlobalErrorHandler());
        //BehaviorExtensionElement
    }
}
```

When I put the break point to provide fault, it shows the following exception as if it is because of parsing:
[image]

How do I handle it so I can send clean error  msg to the client

Edit: 
Postman general exception:

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>Request Error</title>
        <style>
            BODY {
                color: #000000;
                background-color: white;
                font-family: Verdana;
                margin-left: 0px;
                margin-top: 0px;
            }

            #content {
                margin-left: 30px;
                font-size: .70em;
                padding-bottom: 2em;
            }

            A:link {
                color: #336699;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-decoration: underline;
            }

            A:visited {
                color: #6699cc;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-decoration: underline;
            }

            A:active {
                color: #336699;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-decoration: underline;
            }

            .heading1 {
                background-color: #003366;
                border-bottom: #336699 6px solid;
                color: #ffffff;
                font-family: Tahoma;
                font-size: 26px;
                font-weight: normal;
                margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px;
                padding-bottom: 8px;
                padding-left: 30px;
                padding-top: 16px;
            }

            pre {
                font-size: small;
                background-color: #e5e5cc;
                padding: 5px;
                font-family: Courier New;
                margin-top: 0px;
                border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid;
                white-space: pre-wrap;
                white-space: -pre-wrap;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }

            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border-spacing: 0px;
                font-family: Verdana;
            }

            table th {
                border-right: 2px white solid;
                border-bottom: 2px white solid;
                font-weight: bold;
                background-color: #cecf9c;
            }

            table td {
                border-right: 2px white solid;
                border-bottom: 2px white solid;
                background-color: #e5e5cc;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
            <p xmlns="">The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the <a rel="help-page"
                    href="https://localhost:44326/ServiceContracts/CustomerAccount.svc/help">service help page</a> for
                constructing valid requests to the service.</p>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

**Debugger Exceptions:**

> The value '' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'. {"The formatter
>   threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was
>   an error while trying to deserialize parameter :pro. The
>   InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the
>   object of type StilaarAPI.DataContracts.Products. The value '' cannot
>   be parsed as the type 'Int32'.'.  Please see InnerException for more
>   details."}

Comment: Wcf is mainly used for SOAP communications, tho you can create REST methods, I recommend doing restful in web api.

Comment: lets just say its not an option..im stuck with WCF for some reason

Comment: Post your *code* and the exception text, not screenshots of them. The error complains that the `address` field is defined as an *int* and the value passed was an empty string. Where's the class and where's the `address` field?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  pls see the edits, thanks

Comment: Post the code and exception *text*, not screenshots of the code and text. Screenshots can't be copied and compiled. Screenshots of error messages can't be googled

Comment: Besides, those screenshots don't contain any `address` fields. This isn't a WCF issue, most likely it's a bug in the application itself that uses the wrong type the DTO fields. Where are the DTO classes? You can't fix code bugs by modifying the error handling logic, you need to fix the buggy code

Comment: Forget about the address..i was testing with different api earlier, but to smooth things up I have created this get product api.. 
Anyways, could you pls see the edits...I have updated the exception. Thankss

Answer (score 0):

The request body is not authenticated in the local JSON format. It does not satisfy the JSON schema, which means that the request has not yet arrived at the server, so the server does not process it according to the IErrorHandler interface.
It should like the below form so that the request can reach the server.

```
{"Id":null,"Name":"Apple"}
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.
**Updated.**
Do not interfere with the serialization process in the IErrorhandler interface, please consider using the following code to handle errors.

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
        {
            MyError myerror = new MyError()
            {
                Details = error.Message,
                Error = "Hello"
            };
            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, "messsagefault", myerror);
        }
```

Or, we can directly send error details.

```
FaultException faultException = new FaultException(error.Message);
            MessageFault messageFault = faultException.CreateMessageFault();            
            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, error.Message);
```

In addition, we can handle the serialization of messages in IClientMessageFormatter/IDispatcherMessageFormatter.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/custom-message-formatters

Comment: How can I authenticate it?

I did use data annotations like that:

        [DataMember]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address type is required")]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

but its not doing any favors when the property of int is being called.
While on the other hand, strings valkiadtions are working perfectyly fine.

Comment: @Saman the error says nothing about authentication. It complains that `Address` is an int but the posted value was an empty string.

Comment: it seems I have a mistake, the request could reach the IErrorhandler interface. but I can handle all mistakes by the above code. wish it is useful to you.

Comment: @AbrahamQian still happening :(

Comment: @Sanam  On my side, the error could be handled properly with the code segments in the ProvideFault function. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOonD.png